# How to call function/pass value from one class to another in bada using C++ friend function

Tags: c++, friend, bada

I know this is a basic c++ question, but may I know how can I call a function/pass value (elementId) from one class to another in bada using the friend function?

In my form class, I have a listView and when the item in the listView has been clicked, I would like to pass the elementId to detailedForm to display info in the label (in detailedForm). In my form.h and .cpp I have included detailedForm.h, may I know how do I access the function in detailedForm to display the info? In form.h, I have also declared

```
friend class detailedForm;
```

and when I tried to use one of the function in detailedForm in my form class, namely displayInfo(); the form class has an error saying displayInfo() has not been declared.

form.h

```
...
public:
    friend class ChartFormDetail;
```

Here is my code for form.cpp

```
#include "Form.h"
#include "ChartFormDetail.h"
...

void
Form::OnGroupedListViewItemStateChanged(Osp::Ui::Controls::GroupedListView &listView, int groupIndex, int itemIndex, int elementId, Osp::Ui::Controls::ListItemStatus state)
{
    Frame* pFrame = Osp::App::Application::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame();
    FormMgr* pFormMgr = dynamic_cast<FormMgr*> (pFrame->GetControl("FormMgr"));

    if(pFormMgr == null)
    return;

    pFormMgr->SendUserEvent(FormMgr::REQUEST_DETAILFORM, null);
    //pFormMgr->SendUserEvent(elementId, null);


    switch(elementId)
        {
        case ID_FORMAT_STRING_M12:
            DisplayLabel();
            break;
...
        case ID_FORMAT_STRING_F19:
            DisplayLabel();
            break;
        }
}
```

detailedForm.h

```
public:
...
    void DisplayLabel(void);
```

code for detailedForm.cpp

```
void
ChartFormDetail::DisplayInfo(void)
{
    pLabel->SetText("Text here");
    RequestRedraw();
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Leave out anything not related to the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the code as above. Thanks!

Comment: You say the error happens when calling `displayInfo`, but there is no call to `displayInfo` in the code you  posted.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the codes.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to call displayInfo() in your class? You need an object of 'detailedForm' to access it. Also, if you need access the listView data in your friend class (detailedForm), you will need a reference to listView object.

If you're looking for an example to see how friend functions are used, you could check out: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/813-friend-functions-and-classes/

Comment: I called displayInfo() in my listView's fuction: OnGroupedListViewItemStateChanged(...).

Comment: To call ChartFormDetail::displayInfo(), you need an object of class ChartFormDetail. Probably you are directly calling displayInfo without using its object. This is a guess on my end as you've not posted the code for Form::displayLabel. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `displayInfo` is a member-function of `CharFormDetail`. That means you have to call it with an instance of `ChartFormDetail`.

To make it work, you need to do something like this:

```
ChartFormDetail & details = getDetails();
details.displayInfo();
```

This is just an example. I don't know how you would get an instance of `ChartFormDetails`, this depends very much on your architecture.

Comment: sorry, but how do I call it? But I did declared 'friends class ChartFormDetail' in my form.h

Comment: I edited my post to explain a little better. I cannot give you a better answer, as I don't know how you application is structured.

Comment: What do you mean by how my application is structured?? Ok, lets say, I want to pass the elementId of form class to chartformdetail class, then from chartformdetail class, knowing the elementId I should display the correct text for that in the label. How am I supposed to this? Sorry for all these basic questions, I'm still learning. Thanks for your patience and guidance!

Comment: For both classes' .h and .cpp? I will edit and post it up now.

Comment: Please remember to strip all the unnecessary parts - I will not read through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Well, basically the codes I have posted is the main ones. As in, the rest of the unposted codes are all related to listview. I'll just include the .h files